# How to split a string like the following example in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to convert an arbitrary string to an array of strings. The conversion is best explained with an example. If the string were `"8737928"` I would like to return the following array.

```
#=> ["8737928",
#    "8.737928", "87.37928", "873.7928", "8737.928", "87379.28", "873792.8",
#    "8.7.37928", "8.73.7928", "8.737.928", "8.7379.28", "8.73792.8",
#    "87.3.7928", "87.37.928", "87.379.28", "87.3792.8", "873.7.928",
#    "873.79.28", "873.792.8", "8737.9.28", "8737.92.8", "87379.2.8",
#    "8.7.3.7928", "8.7.37.928", "8.7.379.28", "8.7.3792.8", "8.73.7.928",
#    "8.73.79.28", "8.73.792.8", "8.737.9.28", "8.737.92.8", "8.7379.2.8",
#    "87.3.7.928", "87.3.79.28", "87.3.792.8", "87.37.9.28", "87.37.92.8",
#    "87.379.2.8", "873.7.9.28", "873.7.92.8", "873.79.2.8", "8737.9.2.8",
#    "8.7.3.7.928", "8.7.3.79.28", "8.7.3.792.8", "8.7.37.9.28",  "8.7.37.92.8",
#    "8.7.379.2.8", "8.73.7.9.28", "8.73.7.92.8", "8.73.79.2.8", "8.737.9.2.8",
#    "87.3.7.9.28", "87.3.7.92.8", "87.3.79.2.8", "87.37.9.2.8", "873.7.9.2.8",
#    "8.7.3.7.9.28", "8.7.3.7.92.8", "8.7.3.79.2.8", "8.7.37.9.2.8",
#    "8.73.7.9.2.8", "87.3.7.9.2.8",
#    "8.7.3.7.9.2.8"]
```

As you see, between 0 and 6 (`"8737928".size-1 #=> 6`) decimal points are inserted in the string, at every combination of indices between 1 and 6. Since a decimal point may or may not follow each character other than the last, the array contains `2**6 #=> 64` elements.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to loop this or just split a string?

Comment: I want to loop bro. I want to have all output like that. Sorry because i'm not good at english

Comment: Thanking every one for their answer is a nice gesture, but, I think, unwise. Firstly, it doesn't mean much if everyone is thanked, even authors of poor answers. Secondly, if someone gives a really bad answer and you don't thank them, you might as well say, "Your answer stinks". Thirdly, it's a (minor) time-waster for everyone who reads the comments. Look at other questions and you'll see it's just not done (and not expected).

Comment: Thank you. I'm beginer. I will be careful.

Comment: I believe I now understand the question. The problem is that you did not show enough elements of the array to be returned for readers to understand what you wanted. I took the liberty of editing the question. I trust you don't mind and that what I have written accurately describes your intent. I have voted to reopen the question. I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @mudasobwa, please consider reopening (if you have the proper magic dust) or voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

```
def doit(str)
  indices = (1..str.size-1).to_a
  indices.each_with_object([str]) { |ndots, combos|
    indices.combination(ndots).each { |sub| combos << dotify(str, sub) } }
end

def dotify(str, indices)
  indices.reverse.each_with_object(str.dup) { |i,s| s.insert(i,'.') }
end

doit("8737928").size
  #=> 64 

doit "8737928"
  #=> ["8737928",
  #    "8.737928", "87.37928", "873.7928", "8737.928", "87379.28", "873792.8",
  #    "8.7.37928", "8.73.7928", "8.737.928", "8.7379.28", "8.73792.8",
  #    "87.3.7928", "87.37.928", "87.379.28", "87.3792.8", "873.7.928",
  #    "873.79.28", "873.792.8", "8737.9.28", "8737.92.8", "87379.2.8",
  #    "8.7.3.7928", "8.7.37.928", "8.7.379.28", "8.7.3792.8", "8.73.7.928",
  #    "8.73.79.28", "8.73.792.8", "8.737.9.28", "8.737.92.8", "8.7379.2.8",
  #    "87.3.7.928", "87.3.79.28", "87.3.792.8", "87.37.9.28", "87.37.92.8",
  #    "87.379.2.8", "873.7.9.28", "873.7.92.8", "873.79.2.8", "8737.9.2.8",
  #    "8.7.3.7.928", "8.7.3.79.28", "8.7.3.792.8", "8.7.37.9.28",  "8.7.37.92.8",
  #    "8.7.379.2.8", "8.73.7.9.28", "8.73.7.92.8", "8.73.79.2.8", "8.737.9.2.8",
  #    "87.3.7.9.28", "87.3.7.92.8", "87.3.79.2.8", "87.37.9.2.8", "873.7.9.2.8",
  #    "8.7.3.7.9.28", "8.7.3.7.92.8", "8.7.3.79.2.8", "8.7.37.9.2.8",
  #    "8.73.7.9.2.8", "87.3.7.9.2.8",
  #    "8.7.3.7.9.2.8"]
```

Note:

```
dotify("8737928", [1,3,5])
  #=> "8.73.79.28"
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have revised my answer to reflect my current understanding of the question.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

Upon further reflection (see original, probably incorrect solution below), it seems like what OP really wants to do is insert dots at every possible combination of positions in the string.  Here's a method that does literally that:

```
def splits(str, prefix="")
  c = str.size - 1
  (0..c).flat_map do |m|
    (0...c).to_a.combination(m).map do |n|
      n.each_with_object(str.dup) {|i,s| s.insert(c-i, ?.) }
    end
  end
end

puts splits("8737928")
# => 8737928
#    873792.8
#    87379.28
#    87379.2.8
#    8737.928
#    8737.92.8
#    8737.9.28
#    8737.9.2.8
#    873.7928
#    873.792.8
#    873.79.28
#    873.79.2.8
#    873.7.928
#    873.7.92.8
#    873.7.9.28
#    873.7.9.2.8
#    87.37928
#    87.3792.8
#    87.379.28
#    87.379.2.8
#    87.37.928
#    87.37.92.8
#    87.37.9.28
#    87.37.9.2.8
#    87.3.7928
#    87.3.792.8
#    87.3.79.28
#    87.3.79.2.8
#    87.3.7.928
#    87.3.7.92.8
#    87.3.7.9.28
#    87.3.7.9.2.8
#    8.737928
#    8.73792.8
#    8.7379.28
#    8.7379.2.8
#    8.737.928
#    8.737.92.8
#    8.737.9.28
#    8.737.9.2.8
#    8.73.7928
#    8.73.792.8
#    8.73.79.28
#    8.73.79.2.8
#    8.73.7.928
#    8.73.7.92.8
#    8.73.7.9.28
#    8.73.7.9.2.8
#    8.7.37928
#    8.7.3792.8
#    8.7.379.28
#    8.7.379.2.8
#    8.7.37.928
#    8.7.37.92.8
#    8.7.37.9.28
#    8.7.37.9.2.8
#    8.7.3.7928
#    8.7.3.792.8
#    8.7.3.79.28
#    8.7.3.79.2.8
#    8.7.3.7.928
#    8.7.3.7.92.8
#    8.7.3.7.9.28
#    8.7.3.7.9.2.8
```

### Solution 2

However, while @EliSadoff's solution wasn't generalized, I did like his "idea that each spot a period can be is a boolean decision." If we think of the positions in the string at which we could insert a period as bits in a binary number *m* with the same (base 2) length as the string less one, we can simply iterate from 0 to 2<sup>(*c*-1)</sup>-1 (where *c* is the length of the string) to get every possible such number. For example, if our string is `"abcd"` (*c* = 4), then we can iterate from 0 to 7 (2<sup>(4-1)</sup>-1) to find the positions of each period:

```
 m₁₀ | m₂ 4 2 1 |   4   2   1   | result
─────┼────┴─┴─┴─┼───┴───┴───┴───┼─────────
   0 │    0 0 0 │ a   b   c   d │ abcd
   1 │    0 0 1 │ a   b   c • d | abc.d
   2 │    0 1 0 │ a   b • c   d | ab.cd
   3 │    0 1 1 │ a   b • c • d | ab.c.d
   4 │    1 0 0 │ a • b   c   d | a.bcd
   5 │    1 0 1 │ a • b   c • d | a.bc.d
   6 │    1 1 0 │ a • b • c   d | a.b.cd
   7 │    1 1 1 │ a • b • c • d | a.b.c.d
```

The only missing piece is inserting periods based on the bits in the second column. That's pretty easy: To figure out if we need to insert a period at position *n*, we test if the *n*th bit in *m* is 1. To do that we can use the bitwise operation *m* & (1 ≪ *n*).

Put it all together and we get the following:

```ruby
def splits2(str)
  c = str.size - 1
  (0...2**c).map do |m|
    0.upto(c).with_object(str.dup) do |i,s|
      s.insert(c-i, ?.) if m & (1 << i) > 0
    end
  end
end
```

### Solution 3

Just for fun, here's another solution that also uses the binary number approach, but in a different way. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out how it works:

```ruby
def splits3(str)
  c = str.size - 1
  (0...2**c).map do |m|
    dots = ("%*b" % [c,m]).each_char.map(&{?1=>?.})
    str.each_char.zip(dots).join
  end
end
```

### Original solution

Similar to @CarySwoveland's solution but, I think, a bit simpler:

```ruby
def splits(str, pfx="")
  return [] if str.empty?
  (1...str.size).map {|i| pfx + str.dup.insert(i, ?.) } +
    splits(str[1..-1], "#{pfx}#{str[0]}.")
end

p splits("8737928")
# => [ "8.737928", "87.37928", "873.7928", "8737.928", "87379.28", "873792.8",
#      "8.7.37928", "8.73.7928", "8.737.928", "8.7379.28", "8.73792.8",
#      "8.7.3.7928", "8.7.37.928", "8.7.379.28", "8.7.3792.8",
#      "8.7.3.7.928", "8.7.3.79.28", "8.7.3.792.8",
#      "8.7.3.7.9.28", "8.7.3.7.92.8",
#      "8.7.3.7.9.2.8"
#     ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, an improvement.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include three solutions that I think match OP's intent.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements are unclear, and I came up with a result that differs from what both Cary and Jordan have:

```
 def dot_it(prefix, suffix = nil)
   return dot_it(prefix[0], prefix[1..-1]) if suffix.nil? # first call

   (1...suffix.length).flat_map do |i|
     sp, ss = "#{prefix}.#{suffix[0...i]}", suffix[i..-1]
     ["#{sp}.#{ss}", dot_it(sp, ss)].flatten.compact
   end
end
dot_it("8737928")
#⇒ ["8.7.37928", "8.7.3.7928", "8.7.3.7.928", "8.7.3.7.9.28",
#   "8.7.3.7.9.2.8", "8.7.3.7.92.8", "8.7.3.79.28", "8.7.3.79.2.8",
#   "8.7.3.792.8", "8.7.37.928", "8.7.37.9.28", "8.7.37.9.2.8",
#   "8.7.37.92.8", "8.7.379.28", "8.7.379.2.8", "8.7.3792.8",
#   "8.73.7928", "8.73.7.928", "8.73.7.9.28", "8.73.7.9.2.8",
#   "8.73.7.92.8", "8.73.79.28", "8.73.79.2.8", "8.73.792.8",
#   "8.737.928", "8.737.9.28", "8.737.9.2.8", "8.737.92.8",
#   "8.7379.28", "8.7379.2.8", "8.73792.8"]
```

My method gives:

```
dot_it("8737928").count
#⇒ 31
```

while both answers above give 21 results. Who is right?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Plus 6 for the code, plus 4 for the method name.

Comment: But my friends said this question give 64 result. I'm trying to do that.

Comment: It’d be great to review these 64 results.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I’d say method name is way more elegant, than the solution; you should consider swapping assessments to 6 for the method name, 2 for starting a funny chat in comments and 2 for the code.